Manga in which a guy gets the ability class of healer, but due to an error or malfunction, his healing skills get turned into damage dealing skills
The world was an RPG setup like Reality where every citizen can get a class from combat type to support type and some don't awaken any talent once they reach certain age in their school time.
The mc goes to the job awakening crystal and receives lowest rank priest/healer class, but due to an error or some kind of ability (I don't remember much), all of his healing abilities/skills get turned into damage dealing skills (DARK Type skills I think) and he becomes OP while everyone thinks he is weak. When he receives any new skills, they are of healer, but due to the ability/ error they get changed into Damage dealer skills of equivalent rank.
He also solo clears a dungeon portal with his abilities and only one of his female classmates (I think she was elemental ice mage), along with that girl's aunt, knows that he solo cleared the dungeon.
It was a colourful manga. I had read this manga this year only somewhere three to four months ago, I believe. It was in the new recommendation list and only the first 5 to 6 chapters were released at the time. I have already gone through all the new arrivals from the site that I had read the manga already.
That is all I know. Please help me find it.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? Was the main character transported to another world with some classmates? Roughly how many chapters did you read? And roughly when did you read this?

It was colourful manga, I had read this manga this year only somewhere three to four months ago I believe. It was in the new recommendation list and only first 5 to 6 chapters were released at the time. I have already gone through all the new arrivals from the site that I had read the manga already.

The world was an RPG setup where every citizen can get a class from combat type to support type once they reach certain age in their school time. this guy gets f rank priest/ healer class.

You might die if I use my healing skills on you
I've skimmed through the first 5 chapters and it matches many of your points.
It is an VR-RPG-Game made by a god so more like an alternative reality.
The main character receives a skill that allows him to inverse the effects of skills and chooses priest to damage enemies by healing.
It is full color.
Only the part about the female classmate and aunt weren't present or I didn't notice them.


Sorry, but is not what I am looking for. The MC real world has RPG game feature like different fantasy jobs, status windows, skills etc. He does not dive into the game, he is not a returnee in the and their profession is given to them when stand on the "summoned circle", they don't get the liberty to "choose" one from the given list.

Okay I have finally found the manga that I was looking for, the name is
I Am The Shadow Reverend by Kuaikan Manhua.

Traveling through a parallel world, the game merges with the real world, where ferocious beasts are rampant, alien races are raging, and there are a large number of dungeons and secret realms in the wild. Humans can awaken into various professions and work hard to kill monsters and upgrade. On the day of his profession awakening, Lin Luo awakened the priest profession, which is the most popular but has no damage ability. Just when he was struggling, he discovered that his skills had mutated!

Thank you for your answer too @A.Copter.

You can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark.
